# MAIN() function: how does multi-dispatch work?

Tags: raku

Example 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku
use v6.d;

sub MAIN(Int $int) {
    say 'parameter $int: ', $int.^name;
}

--output:--
$ raku b.raku 10   
parameter $int: IntStr
```

Example 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku
use v6.d;

sub MAIN(Str $str) {
    say 'parameter $str: ', $str.^name;
}

--output:--
$ raku b.raku 10   
parameter $str: IntStr

$ raku b.raku hello
parameter $str: Str

$ raku b.raku 10hello
parameter $str: Str

$ raku b.raku 6.5    
parameter $str: RatStr
```

Example 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku
use v6.d;

multi sub MAIN(Int $int) {
    say 'parameter $int: ', $int.^name;
}

multi sub MAIN(Str $str,) {
    say 'parameter $str: ', $str.^name;
}

--output:--
raku b.raku 10     
Ambiguous call to 'MAIN(IntStr)'; these signatures all match:
  (Int $int)
  (Str $str)
  in block <unit> at b.raku line 2
```

Okay, that makes sense to me: an `IntStr` type matches both an `Int` type and a `Str` type.  (In erlang/elixir, the first matching function clause would win.)

Next, if I add an optional parameter to the second clause of MAIN(), the ambiguity disappears:

Example 4:

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku
use v6.d;

multi sub MAIN(Int $int) {
    say 'parameter $int: ', $int.^name;
}

multi sub MAIN(Str $str, Int $x?) {
    say 'parameter $str: ', $str.^name;
}


--output:--
raku b.raku 10
parameter $int: IntSt
```

In this case, the first clause of `MAIN()` executes.  What is the rule to explain that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the second candidate *can* have 2 arguments, it is less tight than the first candidate that must have one argument.

Comment: Some follow on questions naturally arise. Why not make it *tighter*? Because the `Str` variant would match instead of the `Int` one, even though there's no second argument. That would be *more* bizarre. Why isn't it still ambiguous? Because then your final multiple dispatch alternative would cause a failure. That would be *more* unhelpful than it being looser. Doesn't your surprise suggest this aspect of multiple dispatch is fraught? Well, do you think this aspect of Raku's multiple dispatch is fraught, not in theory, on first acquaintance, but in practice, once you have experience with it?

Comment: @raiph, Another example:  one MAIN sub with one Str parameter variable, and a second MAIN sub  with a Str parameter variable and another optional parameter variable.  There is no ambiguity error when a Str argument is used on the command line, but the MAIN sub with the optional parameter will never match one Str argument, so in effect the optional parameter becomes mandatory.

Comment: Hi @7stud. English can be tricky. We need to be careful about it here. A *parameter* (aka [*formal* argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)) is neither optional nor mandatory per se; if there's a parameter in a routine's *declaration* then there's a parameter. Optional / mandatory traits refer to whether there has to be a corresponding *actual argument* in a *call*. In this case that corresponds in turn to an argument on the command line, such that if there *is* one, then the sub that allows one gets called, and if there isn't, then that sub doesn't get called.

Comment: BTW this isn't about `MAIN`. The same thing applies with ordinary routines. `multi foo {}; multi foo {}; foo;` fails with "ambiguous call". `multi foo {}; multi foo ($?) {}; foo;` doesn't.

Comment: @raiph "Why isn't it still ambiguous?"  I'd say, historically because the binder was written before there were any allomorphs yet.  FWIW, I'm on a quest to modernize all of NQP / Metamodel bootstrap / dispatcher (some code hasn't been touched in 13 years).  At one point, I will grok dispatch / the binder enough to start thinking of changes.